# alloc a struct with zero length array using new

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

In C (using gcc) I can declare a variable length struct as below:

```
typedef struct ProtocolFrame
{
     uint8_t      op;
     uint32_t     address;
     uint16_t     size;
     uint8_t      payload[0];
} ProtocolFrame;
```

then I can alloc different frame:

```
ProtocolFrame *frA;
ProtocolFrame *frB;

frA = malloc(sizeof(ProtocolFrame) + 50);
frB = malloc(sizeof(ProtocolFrame));
```

In this example frA has a payload field as big as 50 bytes, and frB has no payload

Can I do the same thing in C++ using the new operator?

Answer (score 9):

```
template<size_t s>
struct ProtocolFrame
{
     uint8_t      op;
     uint32_t     address;
     uint16_t     size;
     uint8_t      payload[s];
} ProtocolFrame;

// specialize for no payload
template<>
struct ProtocolFrame<0>
{
     uint8_t      op;
     uint32_t     address;
     uint16_t     size;
} ProtocolFrame;

ProtocolFrame<50> *frA = new ProtocolFrame<50>;
ProtocolFrame<0> *frB = new ProtocolFrame<0>;
```

To decide what is the size at runtime you could use placement-new operator in cooperation with `std::malloc`:

```
void *buffer = std::malloc(sizeof(ProtocolFrame)+50);
ProtocolFrame *frA = new (buffer) ProtocolFrame;
```

You can read also [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Dynamic_array_template.aspx) on the codeproject.com which is contain the full sample.

Comment: That's not really the same, because by using malloc, he has a dynamically sized extension, whereas this is statically sized.

Comment: You don't necessarily need `std::malloc`. You could write `new char[sizeof(ProtocolFrame) + 50];` but I don't know if that guarantees alignment.

Comment: @Chris: `::operator new(sizeof(ProtocolFrame)+50)` guarantees alignment.

Comment: @Steve - Indeed. I hacked up an (interesting?) implementation of an overloaded new to make instantiating members of a ProtocolFrame-like class a little easier.

Comment: @Chris Lutz, in the article there's a complete solution with overloaded operator new. It too large to place it here, but I recommend to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Use placement new

```
char *buf  = new char[sizeof(ProtocolFrame) + 50];   //pre-allocated buffer
ProtocolFrame *frA = new (buf) ProtocolFrame;  //placement new

// STUFF

frA->~ProtocolFrame();
delete [] buf;
```

when you delete frA it will call ProtocolFrame destructor and free buf allocation

EDIT: I have read that you shouldn't call delete but the destructor directly. I think it might be a compliler specific behaviour. I haven't used placement new much but when I did, I called delete and it worked fine with MSVC++. So the standard correct way seems to be frA->~ProtocolFrame(); and then delete buf;    This looks horrible! I suggest you might want to read up on it.

Comment: Should not be using placement new outside the confines of a class. Otherwise you can not manage the memory correctly when exceptions happen.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would use std::vector.

```
class ProtocolFrame {
    // Invokes undefined behaviour if stuff is not POD.
    struct stuff {
        stuff(uint8_t lop, uint32_t laddress, uint16_t lsize)
            : op(lop), address(laddress), size(lsize) {
        }
        uint8_t op;
        uint32_t address;
        uint16_t size;
    };
    std::vector<uint8_t> payload;
public:
    ProtocolFrame(int payloadsize, uint8_t op, uint32_t address, uint16_t size)
        : payload(size + sizeof(stuff)) {
        new (&payload[0]) stuff(op, address, size);
    }
    // other methods here
    uint32_t GetAddress() {
        return ((stuff*)&payload[0])->address;
    }
    uint16_t GetSize() {
        return ((stuff*)&payload[0])->size;
    }
    uint8_t GetOp() {
        return ((stuff*)&payload[0])->op;
    }
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator begin() {
        return payload.begin() + sizeof(stuff);
    }
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator end() {
        return payload.end();
    }
};
```

This style of code is pretty terrible, though.

Comment: `vector` allocates memory from the heap, obviously OP wants continuous frame.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have classes. Shouldn't the constructor of `ProtocolFrame` get a parameter as to how much `payload` you want?

```
struct ProtocolFrame {
   uint8_t      op;
   uint32_t     address;
   uint16_t     size;
   uint8_t      *payload;

   public:
       ProtocolFrame (int size) {
          payload = new uint8_t [size];
       }

       ~ProtocolFrame () {
          delete [] payload;
       }
 }
```

Comment: You need to either add copy constructor/assignment operator or disable them by making the private or alternatively rather than manage the array you can use a vector.

Comment: a `class` defaults private, a `struct` defaults public for compatibility with existing C code (which has no concept of private or classes).

Comment: @Chris - yes, you are right. I am not sure in what state of mind I wrote the above statement. A `struct` has all members as public unless modified. A `class` has all members as private by default.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still of interest, but you can overload `operator new` to do this. This works with G++ 4.0.1 (I don't know how "nice" it is, feel free to edit and improve it):

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
class test {
  public:
    std::size_t len;
    T arr[1];

    void *operator new(std::size_t s, std::size_t a);

    test(const T& f) { fill(f); }
    test();

  private:
    void fill(const T& f) { for(std::size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) arr[i] = f; }
};

template <typename T>
void *test<T>::operator new(std::size_t s, std::size_t a)
{
    void *p = ::operator new(s + (a - 1) * sizeof(T));
    // this is bad and we shouldn't do this here blah blah blah
    // but I don't know how to pass a to the ctor so this is what I did
    ((test<T> *)p)->len = a;
    return p;
}
```

The usage is not too horrible either:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    test<char> *c = new (10) test<char>('c');
    std::cout << c->arr[3] << std::endl;
    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

Though resize-in-place may not be possible via `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Even in C-style, I think this is **barbarious** code.

and sizeof() your struct will still return the same size.

why don't you treat `payload` as a normal dynamic array ?

EDIT: I do like Kirill V. Lyadvinsky 's answer

EDIT2: @Chris oh I see there are 2 calls to malloc... yes it is less efficient

```
inline ProtocolFrame * createProtocolFrame(int i)
{
    ProtocolFrame * pProto = malloc(sizeof(ProtocolFrame));
    pProto->payload = malloc(i * sizeof(uint8_t));
}
```

Comment: It may be barbarious, but the efficiency may be worth it, and the API functions you write to abstract away these details (you do write those, right?) won't be much different to use than the two-allocation dynamic array approach.

Comment: My point is that the user calls `createProtocolFrame` and doesn't care about what sort of barbarous internals are happening underneath. If efficiency is not an issue, then the OP wouldn't bother with a flexible array member and would use your approach. However, sometimes efficiency _is_ an issue.

Comment: Maybe worth it. If the protocolFrame is created for each and every piece of message sent and received, it may be created often enough for a faster allocation, you are right. But it's not sure until I have seen his code ;-)

Comment: @Chris, yes I have calmed down my "OOP integrist" point of view while writing createProtocolFrame(). Yes sometimes efficiency is an issue.